# creating an array of objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net

It seems like this question gets asked frequently, but having looked through all of them, I find I'm still without aid. I'm taking my first step into oop, and I need to create an object with an attribute "Products" that is an array of up to 7 possible objects of class "Product". I just just barely understand the {get;set;} method, and am reading up on it, but I was hoping I could get some help with the syntax of what I'm trying to do here. I'm using C#. My code is below:

```
public class Submission 
{

    public Submission() {}
    public int SubmissionId {get;set;}

    public int CustId {get;set;}

    public int BroId {get;set;}

    public int Coverage {get;set;}

            public Array Products // what goes here? It's a mystery. 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I think you don't want an auto-implemented property.  Instead, do it like this:

```
//backing store for your public property
private Product[] _products = new Product[7];

public Product[] Products { get {return _products;}}
```

and then in the constructor:

```
foreach(var item in _products) {item = new Product(); }
```

You could do this with a private setter rather than an explicit backing store, but I think this way is easier as far as setting up the size of the array goes.

Notice that I only provided a getter for the property.  You don't want a setter, as that would allow someone to replace your property with a whole new array.  Just providing a getter will still allow someone to manipulate the property.  Also, normally I would recommend a collection rather than an array for this, but since you want a fixed-size for the number of items an array might be a better fit.

Comment: Any reason why you'd prefer an explicit backing field rather than simply having a private setter?

Comment: @Anthony - because of the [7] in the backing store.  I'd use a private setter for lists and other collections. 6 of 1, 1/2 dozen of the other, really.

Answer (score 1):

If you are up to using generic collections, I would use:

```
 public List<Product> Products { get; private set; }
```

or some variation thereof.

Comment: You probably don't want a setter for this property.

Comment: Probably not. Updated to reflect as such.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this:

`public Products[] { get; set; }`

and in the constructor of your class:

`public Submission() {
Products = new Product[7];
}`

Answer (score -1):

Use an `IList`.  You can use the auto property with it.

Comment: Why was the IList downvoted? I saw Joel suggested it first, and then edited to another method. Any reason an IList is a bad idea?